# Why the ith term can be represented in a quadratic form as any difference of $2$ adjacent elements of the sequence is a form of linear?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

$0<a_i$

($1\le i\le n$)

$$\alpha,\beta:=\text{constants for any } i$$

$$a_{i+1}-a_i=\alpha \cdot i+\beta$$

The textbook claims that $a_i$ can be represented in a quadratic form ($bi^{2}+ci^{1}+d$).

Why this claim is adequate?

I thought below.

$$a_{i+1}=\alpha\cdot i+\beta+a_i$$

$$a_2=\alpha\cdot(1)+\beta+a_1 \text{ (linear form)}$$

As 2nd term is a form of linear so the 3rd one will also be a linear one, and same for any $i$

Hence the any term takes a linear form.However actually the textbook states the ith term takes 2nd degree polynomial.

Comment: http://math.kendallhunt.com/documents/daa2/CL/DAA2CL010_07.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$a_4=(a_4-a_3)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_2-a_1)+a_1\,,$$

because the $a_2$ and $a_3$ terms cancel. We can do this for any $a_n$: $$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{i+1}-a_i)+a_1\,.$$

Now you need only know how to calculate the sum of consecutive integers:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{i+1}-a_i)+a_1\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(\alpha i+\beta)-a_1\\
&=\alpha\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i+\beta(n-1)-a_1\\
&=\alpha \cdot\frac{n(n-1)}2+\beta(n-1)-a_1\\
&=\frac{\alpha}2n^2+\left(\beta-\frac{\alpha}2\right)n-(\beta+a_1)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, but too long for a comment:

When a sequence (e.g., $0, 2, 4, 6,\dots$) is described by the recurrence relation $$a_k=a_{k-1}+d\quad(k\geq1),$$ the terms are increasing at a constant “velocity” $d$, so the sequence is called an **arithmetic sequence** with a *common difference* $d,$ and its closed form turns out to be $$a_n=a+(n-1)d\quad(n\geq0).$$

---

When a sequence (e.g. $0, 3, 8, 15, 24,\dots$) is described by the recurrence relation $$a_k=a_{k-1}+dk+c\quad(k\geq1),$$ the terms are increasing at a constant “acceleration” $d$, and its closed form turns out to be $$a_n=\frac d2 n^2+Xn+Y\quad(n\geq0),$$ where X and Y are constants depending on $a_0, c$ and $d$ (refer to @BrianMScott's answer), so the sequence is called a **quadratic sequence** with a *second common difference* $d.$

(Here, there's a constant difference between the difference between successive terms, i.e., the difference between successive terms is changing at a constant rate.)