# Recursive problem - Staircase

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, pattern-recognition

I[image: The following image is a represenation of the problem]

I am working on recursive formulas and I managed to solve the fib formula and got it to

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
F(N) = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2)
```

Now I stumbled on another problem as you can see in the image that's depicting the problem. I need to find a formula but I find it challenging since it's recursive.

I came up with some thoughts:

Let's call the figure **P**

This is the series I came up with:

```
   P:                                      1          2        3         4        5
   Number of blocks:                       0          1        7         22       50
   The amount of blocks in the base:       0          1        6         15       22
```

You can probably see a pattern here. P is determined by adding together the amounts of blocks in each base in the previous figure.

For instance figure 4, has 22 stone blocks in total. We can do that by adding up 15 + 6 + 1 + 0 = 22

You can also see that the width increases by 1 and the length increases by 2 for each **P**.

The problem I have here is implementing this pattern as a function, just like I did with the Fib series. I appreciate some help.

This is how I've started:

```
F(1) = 0
F(2) = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  P:                              1     2      3      4       5
>  number of blocks in the base:   0     1      6      15      22
>  total number of blocks, F(P):   0     1      7      22      50
> ```
>
> This is how I've started:
>   $F(1) = 0$
>   $F(2) = 1$

We want a recurrence relation that relates $F(P+1)$ and $F(P),$ were $P$ is the term number according to your table above.

> You can also see that the width increases by 1 and the length increases by 2 for each **P**.

This is the key observation. Thus, \begin{align}F(P+1)&=F(P)+\text{width $\times$ length of the added rectangle}\\&=F(P)+P\times\text{the $P$th term of the arithmetic sequence with first term $1$ and common difference $2$}\\&=F(P)+P \times \big(1+ (P-1)2\big)\\&=F(P)+2P^2-P.\end{align}

---

**Supplement to the above answer**

Recap: the above recurrence system is $$F(1)=0,\\F(P+1)=F(P)+2P^2-P\quad (P\in\mathbb N).$$

- It describes a sequence with a constant “jerk” (third common
  difference)—in this case, $4$—so it has a cubic
  [closed-form
  expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4075459/21813).

  So, to derive it, plug $P=1,2,3$ into
  $$F(P)=aP^3+bP^2+cP+d$$ and solve simultaneously:$$\left.
     \begin{array}{l} 0&=&a+b+c+d\\ 1&=&8a+4b+2c+d\\ 7&=&27a+9b+3c+d\\
     22&=&64a+16b+4c+d \end{array} \right\} \iff a = \frac23 , b =
     -\frac32 , c = \frac56 , d = 0.$$ Thus, $$F(P)=\frac23P^3-\frac32P^2+\frac56P.$$
- Alternatively, its closed form can be derived using [telescoping
  cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series):
  \begin{align}F(P+1)-F(P)&=2P^2-P\\&\vdots\\&\vdots
     \\F(P+1)-F(1)&=2(1^2+2^2+\ldots+P^2)-(1+2+\ldots+P)\\F(P+1)-0&=2\left(\frac{P(P+1)(2P+1)}6\right)-\left(\frac{P(P+1)}2\right)\\F(P)&=2\left(\frac{(P-1)P(2(P-1)+1)}6\right)-\left(\frac{(P-1)P}2\right)\\&=\frac23P^3-\frac32P^2+\frac56P.\end{align}

Comment: Does this work even though the figures in the picture is depicting figure N = 2 (1 block), N = 3 (7 blocks) and N = 4 ( 22 blocks)? The first staircase isn’t even shown in the picture. The first block is N = 1 and has 0 stone blocks. I appreciate an answer :)

Comment: @leun I've just revised my Answer according to your request.

Comment: Thanks! I got a question though if I want to express this formula where F(P) is on the left-hand side, how am i supposed to do? I tried to do F(P) = F(P + 1) - (2P^2 - P) but wont get it to work

Comment: @leun I've expanded the Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this case you aren't just adding the two previous terms. You're adding a layer around the blocks.

Notice that in the Nth layer, you are adding $(N-1) * (2N-3)$ blocks.

So, a plausible function would be $f(N) = f(N-1) + (N-1)(2N-3)$, where $f(1)=0, f(2)=1$.

Comment: You sure this is right? Wjem N = 5 I get it to 89

Comment: You might've made a mistake. 1 + 6 + 15 + 28 (not 22) + 45 = 95.

Comment: Actually, 45 when it's supposed to be 50

Comment: Where does 50 come from? For me, I multiplied 1x1, 2x3, 3x5, 4x7, and 5x9

Comment: Yea but look at the picture. when N = 3 for instance the number of blocks are supposed to be 7. 

The picture is depicting figure number N = 2 (1 block), N = 3 (7 blocks) and N = 4 (22 blocks)

Comment: That's an easy fix, i'll edit my answer to accommodate that. I interpreted it as starting with N=0, not N=1

Comment: Cheers it works out now. May I ask you how you got it to (N-1) * (2N - 3)? Like how did you come up with that?

Comment: I wanna know how to solve such problems, so I wanna know how you came up with that solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach very much in the spirit of recursion: Let $f(n)$ denote the number of blocks in the $n$-th pile, and $w(n)$ and $l(n)$ the width and length of $n$-th layer. Here the first pile consists of one block, so that $f(0)=w(0)=l(0)=0$ and $f(1)=w(1)=l(1)=1$. Then we get the recursive formula
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+w(n+1)\cdot l(n+1)\tag{1}.$$
As you note, going from one layer to the next, the width increases by $1$ and the length increases by $2$, so
$$w(n+1)=w(n)+1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad l(n+1)=l(n)+2.$$
These are two simple linear recursions, with solutions $w(n)=n$ and $l(n)=2n-1$. Plugging this back into $(1)$ yields
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+n\times(2n-1).$$
It also gives you the direct formula
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^nk\times(2k-1).$$
From here you can express $f$ as a polynomial in $n$ using the well-known closed forms for $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$.

---

Note that counting the pile of one layer, with one block, as the first pile gives a nicer indexing of the sequence. You get $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Thank you! How do I express f(n+1)=f(n)+n×(2n−1) when f(n) is in the Left Side. 

Should it be f(n) = f(n + 1) - n * (2n -1)